# Forming faces out of a list of lines

Tags: c++

I am given a list of lines `beginendLines` (using the index of each point)

```
line0 = (0,1)
line1 = (1,2)
line2 = (2,3)
line3 = (3,0)
line4 = (4,5)
line5 = (5,6)
line6 = (6,7)
line7 = (7,4)
line8 = (0,4)
line9 = (1,5)
line10 = (2,6)
line11 = (3,7)
line12 = (0,5)
line13 = (0,8)
line14 = (1,8)
line15 = (5,8)
line16 = (1,9)
line17 = (2,9)
line18 = (6,9)
line19 = (5,9)
line20 = (4,10)
line21 = (5,11)
line22 = (6,12)
line23 = (7,13)
line24 = (10,11)
line25 = (11,12)
line26 = (12,13)
line27 = (13,10)
```

Now I need to find a way to figure out how to create faces with these. What i tried so far:

```
int progress = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i< beginendLines.size(); i+=2){
    if (progress == 0){
        Face addface;
        addface.point_indexes.push_back(beginendLines[i]);
    }
    else{
        addface.point_indexes.push_back(beginendLines[i+1]);
        progress = 0;
    }
    if (i != beginendLines.size - 2){   
        if (beginendLines[i+2] != beginendLines[i+1]){
            progress = 1;
            figuur.faces.push_back(addface);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem with this approach is that with each for loop, a new face would be generated. Also because of the if loops, there are quite a few things out of scope. Anyone who could help me out with a different approach or a restructurisation of my code?

Face is a class, containing consisting of a vector with indexes of the points that would create a face. `e.g. 0,1,2,3`

```
class Face{
public: 
    vector<int> point_indexes;
};
```

A bit clearer on what I'm trying to accomplish: 
`figuur.faces.push_back(addface)` should push a face to `figuur.faces`. A face should be 2 points minimum (begin and endpoint of 1 line), and as long as the start of the next line is equal to the end of the last line, the end index of the next line should be added to the face.

Comment: What is the type `Face` and how is it defined? And I fail to see how this rather simplistic code would produce a recognizable "face" of any sort.

Comment: I recommend that you update your question title to indicate that you mean **graph** faces (or whatever kind of face you actually mean). People will think you're trying to do face recognition.

Comment: *Face is a class, containing consisting of a vector* -- It won't hurt if you actually posted the class instead of describing it.

Comment: So what really is the question?  You declared a local `Face` here: `Face addface;` that gets destroyed on every iteration.  Also, that code could not compile since `addface` is local inside the `if` block.  But other than that, your question is not clear as to what you are having trouble accomplishing.

Answer (score 1):

## For Loop Issues

```
for (int i = 0; i< beginendLines.size(); i+=2)
```

The issue with this is that when `i == bigenendLines.size() - 1` and 
`bigenendLines.size() % 2 == 0` you're going to go out of bounds when you try to access an item at `i+1` with `beginendLines[i+1]`

Here's one possible fix:

```
for (int i = 0; i< beginendLines.size()-1; i+=2)
```

Or use  an iterator loop:

```
for(lineIterator = beginendLines.begin(); 
    lineIterator != beginendLines.end(); 
    lineIterator++)
```

If you have access to C++11 then you should be able to do a range based for loop (I'm not sure it's a good idea for this case though):

```
 for (const Line& line : beginendLines)
```

## Scoping Issues

Your next issue is that your `addface` isn't properly scoped. You're defining it in the if statement and then using it in the else statement (and the if statement after that).

```
if (progress == 0){
    Face addface;
    addface.point_indexes.push_back(beginendLines[i]);
}
else{
    addface.point_indexes.push_back(beginendLines[i+1]); // HOW?
    progress = 0;
}
```

You should define `addface` in the for loop before the if statement e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i< beginendLines.size()-1; i+=2) 
{
    Face addface;
    Other stuff;
}
```

## Other problems

I'd question the logic that you're using in your for loop. Mainly what you are trying to achieve, whether `process` is needed and whether `if (i != beginendLines.size - 2)` is needed.

## A note on creating objects every iteration

If you have a vector of faces and are expecting to push a face to the vector every loop iteration, then it's only natural that you'd have to create a face every loop iteration. If you don't push `addface` to the vector then I'm pretty sure it goes out of scope and gets destroyed so you don't need to worry about all these faces filling up your heap every loop iteration.